# ASP.NET MVC3 Custom Route Mapping?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, action

the url like:

```
/query/test/p1s1c1
```

the action is:

```
public ActionResult Test(int price = 1, int size = 1, int category = 1)
{
    ViewBag.param = "price:" + price + "size:" + size + "category" + category;
    return View();
}
```

my route mapping is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Query", // Route name
    "Query/test/p{price}s{size}c{category}",
    new { controller = "Query", action = "Test", price = UrlParameter.Optional, size = UrlParameter.Optional, category = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { price = @"\d+", size = @"\d*" , category = @"\d*" } // Parameter defaults 
    );
```

but it not work,who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the frameworks handles URL requests, it tries to match the URL of the request to a route in the order of the `Routes` are added to the `RouteCollection`.

So put your route **before** the default route and it should work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Query", // Route name
                ///...
                );

routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                ///...
               );
```

Now the with the url : `/query/test/p2s2c2` the executed Test action will have the parameters: `price = 2, size = 2, category = 2`

You can read more about [How URLs Are Matched to Routes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#how_urls_are_matched_to_routes).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Query", // Route name
    "Query/test/{price}/{size}/{category}",
    new { controller = "Query", action = "Test", price = UrlParameter.Optional, size = UrlParameter.Optional, category = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { price = @"\d+", size = @"\d*" , category = @"\d*" } // Parameter defaults 
    );
```

and after that default route....